# Can someone explain this sed command?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

So the text is the following:

```
1a fost odata
2un balaur
care fura
mere de aur
```

and after using this command:

```
sed 's/\([a-z]*\)\(.*\)\( [a-z]*\)/\1 ... \2/' filename
```

the result is this:

```
... 1a fost
 ... 2un balaur
care ...
mere ...  de
```

I know that `\1` is for the first `[a-z]*` subexpression and so on, but I just can't figure this out.. also, what's the difference between the first subexpression and the last one? why is there a space before `[a-z]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `[a-z]*` matches the first sequence of letters on the line. The `*` quantifier matches 0 or more repetitions, so this can also match an empty string.

On the first line it matches the empty string before `1a`. On the second line it matches the empty string before `2un`. On the third line it matches `care`, and on the fourth line it matches `mere`. These matches will go into capture group 1.

`.*` matches zero or more of any characters, so this will skip over everything in the middle of the line. These matches go into capture group 2.

`[a-z]*` matches a space followed by zero or more letters. The space is needed to make `.*` stop matching when it gets to the last space on the line. These matches go into capture group 3.

The replacement is capture groups 1 and 2 with `...` between them. This is the letters at the beginning of the line, `...`, then everything after that except the last word.

Comment: Thank you, but im afraid i still dont understand .* ... So, you said it skips over everything in the middle of the line, but why does it match with 1a 2un and de, but not with fura?

Comment: Because it stops at the last space so that space followed by `[a-z]*` can match.